# glCompileShader status is false but the log is empty

Tags: c++, opengl

when I call glCompileShader() for the vertex shader, and use glGetShaderiv to get the status, it returns a false. However when I look at the log, it is empty. I'm new to shaders so I'm sure i've done something wrong. Here is my code:

```
void GLSLProgram::compileShader(const std::string& filePath, GLuint id)
{
    /*Shader Program Reading*/
    //don't worry about this \/, it just loads my shader program from the file.
    std::string shader = gdcUtil::implode(gdcFile::readBlock(filePath, 0, 0, '\n', 0, true), true);

    const char* shaderPtr = shader.c_str();

    /*Shader Source Refering*/
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &shaderPtr, nullptr);

    /*Shader Compiling*/
    glCompileShader(id);
    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE) {
        //Setup Error Log
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);
        std::string log;
        for (int i = 0; i < errorLog.size(); i++) {
            log += errorLog[i];
        }
        gdcUtil::error(log, "GD_GLSL");
        glDeleteShader(id);
        gdcUtil::quit();
    }
}
```

Vertex Shader Program:

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

I know for a fact that it loads the shader program correctly, just fails upon compilation.

EDIT: Here is the code that calls compileShader

```
//Create Shaders
_vertID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
bool shaderValid = glIsShader(_vertID);
if (_vertID = 0) {
    gdcUtil::error("Could not create Vertex Shader", "GD_GLSL");
    gdcUtil::quit();
}
_fragID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
if (_fragID = 0) {
    gdcUtil::error("Could not create Fragment Shader", "GD_GLSL");
    gdcUtil::quit();
}

//Compile Shaders
compileShader(vertFilePath, _vertID);
compileShader(fragFilePath, _fragID);
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the shader id is valid? To double check, you could call `glIsShader(id)` at the start of this code. Also, make sure that you call `glGetError()` to check for possible errors.

Comment: GL implementations are not required to provide diagnostic messages if shader compilation fails, although most of them do. I've only experienced compiler errors with no log message at all on GLES. What GPU are you using, and what GL version?

Comment: @RetoKoradi glIsShader(id) returns false. I guess the id is messed up?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I posted the code that calls compileShader, and the id is valid up until i pass it through to compileShader.

Comment: @derhass I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card, using GLEW version 1.13.0

Comment: `if (_vertID = 0)`: Why are you overwriting `_vertID` with zero?

Comment: @genpfault wow, i completely missed that. should be ==. can't believe that was it. Thank you